# Where can I see the removed SAPUI5 versions?

Tags: sapui5, version, cdn

Can someone tell me why the SAPUI5 version "1.56.16" stopped working? (using CDN).
I know they have been removing some outdated versions, but, I don't see this one on the list.
Or maybe I don't understand which ones are getting removed...

[Versions List](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You actually answered your question yourself: You can find this information on the [SAPUI5 Version Overview Page](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html).

If you check there table *SAPUI5 Versions Maintenance Status* you can see that 1.56 is an interim version as it never had long term maintenance. So this means this version went out of maintenance when 1.58 was available or rather in case of consumption via FES when 1.60 was available (which was around Q1/2018).
In column *End of Cloud Provisioning* you can see that the removal of 1.56 was scheduled for Q1/2022. That's why also 1.56.6 is not available anymore.
The schedule when a patch will be removed can be found below in table *Available SAPUI5 Versions on SAP Business Technology Platform*, but only as long as they are available. As a rule of thumb patches will be removed if they are older than one year or rather with the End of Cloud Provisioning of the respective SAPUI5 version.

It is important to understand that the removal of outdated SAPUI5 versions will happen at regular intervals, each and every time when a patch is older than one year or rather a version is out of maintenance for one year.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because my specific patch did not appear on the list. Also I have other applications using the '1.28.52' and '1.72.7' versions and still working... It got me very confused. Does this mean they still haven't removed them yet?

Comment: According to the list "Available SAPUI5 Versions on SAP Business Technology Platform" 1.28.52 should be removed ans when I try to call https://ui5.sap.com/1.28.52/ I also get the relevant error message. Your app might still work as it gets the resources from the cache? 
1.72.7 is still there, but as End of Cloud Provisioning was Q1/22, so you can expect that this version will also be removed within the next weeks.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm going to take action and upgrade them. Thanks again!